# Drupal: URL to create new book

Tags: drupal

I know how to add a childpage to an existing book, with an url like this:

```
/node/add/book?parent=9228
```

The last number is the book page's id.

How can I set it to create a new book?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have looked at the code but as far as I can see, Drupal does not offer that possibility by default. I'm not 100% sure if this works, but you could try to install the [prepopulate module](http://drupal.org/project/prepopulate) and use this:

```
/node/add/book?edit[book][bid]=new
```